# How to find elements by one class, but exclude other using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple elements with a class like

```
<li class="target-class exclude-class"></li>
<li class="target-class exclude-class"></li>
<li class="target-class"></li>
<li class="target-class"></li>
<li class="target-class"></li>
```

I would like to find elements with target-class only if they dont have exclude-class. I tried

```
var elements = $find('.target-class exclude-class:not');
```

But I get all the elements

Comment: A simple lookup of `:not`  or `.not()` in jQuery api docs would have answered this yourself. There are examples for each also. Some basic research is expected before asking questions here

Comment: Yes I find it, but don use correctly ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are not using the `:not` selector correctly.
You can select the elements for this scenario either using the [**not**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) method or the [**:not**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

```
  $('.target-class:not(.exclude-class)');  // :not selector
```

or

```
$('.target-class').not('.exclude-class'); // .not method
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3325v2L/)**

Comment: to add to the answer the CSS3 selector is faster. not that big of a difference in most cases. here's a jsperf https://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not

Comment: @GiancarloVenturaGranados Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.not()` method:

```js
var elements = $('.target-class').not('.exclude-class');

console.log(elements.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="target-class exclude-class">1</li>
<li class="target-class exclude-class">2</li>
<li class="target-class">3</li>
<li class="target-class">4</li>
<li class="target-class">5</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your query syntax is not correct. It should be as following:

```
var elements =$find('.target-class:not(.exclude-class'));
```

or

```
var elements =$find('.target-class').not('.exclude-class');
```